# Symfony routing подключение внешнего resource и имя Bundle

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Я пытаюсь взять маршруты из внешнего файла в Symfony 4 routes и не могу понять, что является именем Bundle.

Файл routes.yml:

```
icatcher_builder:
    # loads routes from the given routing file stored in some bundle
    resource: '@ICatcher/Builder/Resources/config/routes.yaml'
```

Файл bundles.php:

```
App\ICatcher\Builder\Builder::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
```

И я получаю такую ошибку в разных варинтах - я пробовала подставлять весь namespace как имя - App\ICatcher\Builder\Builder и App\ICatcher\Builder\Builder::class:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Bundle "ICatcher" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your App\Kernel.php file? in @ICatcher/Builder/Resources/config/routes.yaml (which is being imported from "[PATH]\config/routes.yaml"). Make sure the "ICatcher/Builder/Resources/config/routes.yaml" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class. If the bundle is registered, make sure the bundle path "@ICatcher/Builder/Resources/config/routes.yaml" is not empty.").
```

Если я просто прописываю содержимое подключаемого файла в основной routes.yml ошибок нет и Bundle работает, из чего я (видимо) делаю вывод, что Bundle подключен и я не правильно понимаю синтаксис - как должно выглядить имя Bundle в routes.yaml?

Comment: Эх, понимать бы что такое внешний файл В Symfony.

Comment: Еще один routes.yaml, который живет в моей Bundle - с маршрутами для этой Bundle. Я его пытаюсь подключить в основном routes.yaml - как в посте - resource: '@[Тут должно быть правильное имя Bundle]/config/routes.yaml'

Comment: Возможно что то изменилось со времен 3.4, однако бандлы имеют совершенно определенную структуру и как минимум нужно ожидать при их подключении увидеть что то типа ICatcherBundle::class к тому же не  пытаетесь ли вы в проде  запустить ? Ведь у вас этот бандл судя по всему включен  в dev  и test окружении.

Comment: Я не пользовалась Symfony до 4ой версии, но концепт Bundle тут другой, насколько я понимаю.. Namespace у меня у осного класса Bundle получается App\ICatcher\Builder и имя самого класса Builder. Запускаю в dev - да и если не подключать маршруты из внешнего файла, а скопировать их в основной - все работает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Symfony жесткие правила названий для классов Bundle classes, что было обнаружено в документации, почему-то в разделе Best Practices: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html

Там сказанно, что название класса должно включать название Вендора.

Мой класс Bundle был переименован из `App\ICatcher\Builder\Builder` в `App\ICatcher\Builder\ICatcherBuilder` и файл был переименован `ICatcherBuilder.php` и все заработало.